# How to prevent whitespace under slick.js slider using Viewheight

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a slick.js slider within a section in my mobile webpage. Under the slider is extra whitespace, setting the view-height to 23.5 helps when the device viewing the page is a certain height. When the height of the device viewing the page changes the whitespace re-appears.(Works fine on Iphone 7, however on Iphone X for example there is whitespace under the slider)

I have attempted setting the height to viewheight 23.5 which works when its viewed on an Iphone 7, but on devices with different heights the whitespace re-appears.

```
<section id="projects-section pt-3" class = "hidemeXL" style="height: 23.5vh" > 

<?php echo do_shortcode('[project_manager_display numposts="15" transition_type="fade" size="slick" scroller="true" featured="true"]');?>

<div class="your-class slick-initialized slick-slider">
 <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
      <div class="slick-track" role="listbox" style="opacity: 1; width: 6960px; transform: translate3d(-1305px, 0px, 0px):
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

I expect the slider to be flush against the bottom and top elements surrounding it.

EDIT: I added some more code that shows up when viewing in inspect element, everything after the php block is not code I have written, but code that is generated by the slick.js library.

Comment: Could be a number of things, usual culprit would be css float/position. Some code would give us a better idea

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to look this over. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Vlad, I assumed the same thing however can not seem to figure out what it is. I will attempt to provide more code, however most of the code does not relate to this element whatsoever.